# How to stop Ajax.ActionLink inside jQuery tree item from propagating click to tree item

Tags: jquery, click, actionlink

Normally, as I understand, you return false from jQuery click handler, and that stops click from going further. How would I achive the same behavior with Ajax.ActionLink?
Tree items use click to expand and collaps, and clicking on Ajax.ActionLink causes both action link to be executed and tree item collapsed/expanded.

Comment: I have the same question, How do you stop event propagation coming from an Ajax.ActionLink.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **event.preventDefault();** and **event.stopPropagation();**

```
$('#yourdiv a.collapse').live('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```